# How to prevent data studio from formating numbers

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I created a form in Google sheets where I register codes and the number format is always 3 digits. In order to work, I chose the following: (Format>Number>More formats>Custom Number Formats, registered "000" and saved). It shows now perfectly in Sheets.
When I create a table in data studio, i have issues with all numbers starting with 0 (like 000,007,068), they return empty for 000, return 68 instead of 068...

Anyone has an idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inserting a helper column next to the numbers column `N` and put this formula in row 1 of the new column:

`=arrayformula( text(N1:N, "000") )`

Then use the new text-only column in Data Studio instead of the numeric column.